# Properties not passing to from in VB.NET custom control

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, visual-studio-2005

I have a custom VB.NET control that I created that is working correctly in one program but not in another. The control has one button and one form. The form displays some data based on the settings in the control.

This is the use in both test projects:

```
With Me.MyControl1
    '.Connection = gConn
    .Server = "servername"
    .DBName = "dbname"
    .TableName = "table"
    .FieldString = "list of fields"
    .ReturnColumn = 0
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
End With
```

This is how I am passing the settings to my form.

...this form is a part of the control

```
Public Sub New(ByVal cmsl As MyCustomControl)
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.Connection = cmsl.Connection
    Me.ConnectionString = cmsl.ConnectionString
    Me.Server = cmsl.Server
    Me.DBname = cmsl.DBName
    Me.TableName = cmsl.TableName
    Me.FieldString = cmsl.FieldString
    Me.FilterString = cmsl.FilterString
    Me.AllowMultiSelect = cmsl.AllowMultiSelect
    Me.AutoPopulate = cmsl.AutoPopulate
    Me.ReturnColumn = cmsl.ReturnColumn
    Me.SelectTop = cmsl.SelectTop

End Sub
```

In TestProject1 - the control is working as expected
In TestProject2 - the control is not sending any of the settings I set to the form

My control works fine when I debug with the UserControl TestContainer.

I am using VB.NET on VS2005.

This is all done on the same machine. Why would this work in one project and not another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a reference error. please show us how the UserControl is integrated. The problem must come from there.

And are you talking about a custom control, or a UserControl ? (Not the same thing for me)

Try some breakpoints in the props, and also, try checking the references :). You might be working with a second usercontrol overlapping on the first one or something like that :).

In winforms the Designer sometimes goes weird.

Comment: Its a custom control. I will try this an see what I can find out.

Comment: It was something dumb and simple. The control was renamed when I dragged it on the designer (i must have dragged it on when another one was on it). I must have overlooked that when I was reviewing it. Thanks for the reply squelos.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was something like that. Looked far too weird to be anything else. I happen to experience the same type of issues with my application which uses a lot of User controls. The winforms designer doesnt like errors in the User Controls, and sometimes deletes/renames my user controls. Sometimes only partially, so i cant find them visually anywhere, and in the .designer, only half the declarations/attributes are there ... Produces really weird stuff :D